# How to set VM parameters from Spring with value from .properties?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a big projects made with spring. In this project I import different jars with the POM. One of these jars uses a VM parameter to load a configuration file. I want to set the path of this file whit System.setProperty taking the value from a .properties spring file. How can I do? I try yo create a class whit @COnfiguration annotation and with init method but the method is never called.

*Edit:*

I have used the @PostContruct annotation, but I have problem with the configuration order of the file. I also tried the @Order annotation.

Comment: Spring can read properties files at startup.  It won't be Maven using it; it'll be the JVM.  By the time Spring runs, the app has been started.

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, write it here, why.